# Write multiple pandas dataframes to excel

Tags: python, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I am attempting to write multiple pandas `dataframes` which I extracted from a larger dataset into multiple worksheets of an excel workbook. The issue is that it only writes the first dataframe i.e. `index[0]`, so the resulting workbook has only one worksheet, see `sheet1` below. What am I missing? This is a recreation of my problem.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

df_list = []
a = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 'B':[10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]})
b = pd.DataFrame({'C':[11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99], 'D':[105,117,128,139,140,153,166,176,188]})

df_list.append(a)
df_list.append(b)

writer = ExcelWriter('test_output.xlsx')
for n, df in enumerate(df_list):
    df.to_excel(writer, 'sheet%s' % str(n + 1))
    writer.save()
```

Sheet1:

```
    A   B
0   1   10
1   2   11
2   3   12
3   4   13
4   5   14
5   6   15
6   7   16
7   8   17
8   9   18
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to call `writer.save()` or `writer.close()` in later API after the `for` construct.

Once this method is called, the `writer` object is effectively closed and you will not be able to use it to write more data.

```
writer = ExcelWriter('test_output.xlsx')
for n, df in enumerate(df_list):
    df.to_excel(writer, 'sheet%s' % str(n + 1))
writer.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for shedding light on this.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that saving the writer would close it.

Comment: They must have changed the API, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74948525/futurewarning-save-is-not-part-of-the-public-api-in-python)