# How to import dats from one sheet to another sheet based on Substring using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

My goal here is to import the data stored as DataFrame df1 in sheet1 based on the substring.

My DataFrame looks like below:

```
df:[2 x 8]

    ordercode           quantity
PMC11-AA1L1FAVWJA        20
PMC21-AA1A1CBVXJA        10
PMP11-AA1L1FAWJJ          5
PMP21-AA1A1FBWJJ          3
PMP23-AA1A1FA3EJ+JA       1
PTP31B-AA3D1HGBVXJ        1
PTC31B-AA3D1CGBWBJA       2
PTP33B-AA3D1HGB1JJ        10
```

But my desired result should be like

```
Sheet2_df2:"1C"
   ordercode           quantity
PMC21-AA1A1CBVXJA        10
PTC31B-AA3D1CGBWBJA       2

Sheet3_df3:"1F"
PMP11-AA1L1FAWJJ          5
PMP21-AA1A1FBWJJ          3
PMC11-AA1L1FAVWJA        20
```

In excel it is easy by creating a criteria and use IF function.
    B1: "1C"

```
 =IF(Sheet1!A2=$B$1,Sheet1!A2,"")
```

and could copy to all cell.

I don't know how to perform this in python.
Any solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First read your data into a Pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
```

Then use a dictionary comprehension with `pd.Series.str.contains`:

```
substrings = ['1C', '1F']

d = {x: df[df['ordercode'].str.contains(x, na=False, regex=False)] for x in substrings]
```

You can then access dataframes via substring keys, e.g. `d['1C']`. If you wish, you can export each value in your dictionary to a separate worksheet or workbook. For example:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    v.to_excel(f'{k}.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you explain how this For function works here. whether I can export both the columns  for each substring? How this 'k' works here?

Comment: `both the columns` not sure what you mean here. This is a simple `for` loop which iterates keys and values from your dictionary. Each key is a substring, e.g. `'1C'`, each value is a dataframe, e.g. a dataframe filtered for `'1C'` in `df['ordercode']`.

Comment: Okay. I understood. Thanks let me try this.

Comment: Hey. It worked. but I need the data in same Excel file in different sheet. How can I do that ??

Comment: @user10309160, See [Write multiple pandas dataframes to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315010/write-multiple-pandas-dataframes-to-excel)

Comment: I tried to export the data to different sheets in same Excel using below codes `writer=pd.ExcelFile('file.xlsx')`   in For loop `v.to_excel(writer,f'{k}.xlsx',index= False)`  but its overwriting in same sheet.

Comment: @user10309160, Please see my previous comment. This isn't a help forum. If I solved your original question, consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Feel free to ask a new question if my previous comment doesn't help.

Comment: I have followed the instruction in your previous comment but I'm getting error. your method helped me. Thanks