# FutureWarning: save is not part of the public API in Python

Tags: python, excel, warnings

I am using Python to convert Pandas df to .xlsx (in Plotly-Dash app.). All working well so far but with this warning tho:

**"FutureWarning:
save is not part of the public API, usage can give unexpected results and will be removed in a future version"**

How should I modify the code below in order to keep its functionality and stability in future? Thanks!

```
 writer = pd.ExcelWriter("File.xlsx", engine = "xlsxwriter")

 workbook  = writer.book

 df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Sheet', index = False)
  
 writer.save()
```

Comment: See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.close.html#pandas.ExcelWriter.close

Answer (score 33, accepted):

just replace save with close.

```
 writer = pd.ExcelWriter("File.xlsx", engine = "xlsxwriter")

 workbook  = writer.book

 df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Sheet', index = False)
  
 writer.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try any of these options, and it should work:
Replace:

```
writer.save()
```

by

```
    writer._save()
or
    writer.close()
```

Comment: If `.save()` isn't "part of the public API", then `._save()` is for sure not